# Как добавить превью к видео на ютуб, но что бы оно не грузило само видео?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

Всем привет

На странице есть несколько ютуб видео, но если их разом добавить, то страница жутко долго грузится. Нужно добавить превью видео, а если по нему кликнуть, то видео загрузится в контейнер. Сейчас у меня такая реализация:

```
<a class="img_slide video_0" href="#"></a>
function addVideoYoutube() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('video_0')[0];
    var el2 = document.getElementById('ytplayer');
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        el2.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/99-n42Xb6NQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    });

}
```

Но на тэге а сейчас просто картинка, а нужно именно превью, как тут
http://joxi.ru/p27RGOBCpaznm7 
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В параметрах проигрывателя youtube (как через iframe, так и через flash player) есть параметр [controls](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru#controls). Используйте его для вставки любого видео на страницы сайта и у вас не будет проблем с их загрузкой.

> controls=2 – элементы управления отображаются в проигрывателе. При
> встраивании IFrame отображаются элементы управления, а проигрыватель
> Flash загружается после того, как пользователь начнет воспроизведение
> видео.
>
> Примечание. Значения параметра 1 и 2 одинаково работают с точки зрения
> пользователя, однако значение controls=2 обеспечивает увеличение
> производительности по сравнению со значением controls=1 при
> встраивании IFrame.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хорошо, можно ли как то при клике на видео добавить его загрузку в контейнер?

Comment: @NikitaShchypylov, "начало работы" прямо с живым примером официальный ответ, но там и без этого много интересного https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ru#Getting_Started