# Youtube, HTML5 и Ajax загрузка

Tags: ajax, html5, youtube

[Данный скрипт вставляет видео с YouTube без iframe](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)
Проблема в том, что на сайте, где вставляется видео посты подгружаются через Ajax и вот в этих постах уже черный экран вместо видео. 
[тут есть решение для flowplayer](https://foliovision.com/support/fv-wordpress-flowplayer/troubleshooting/fv-player-on-dynamically-loaded-posts)

Как реализовать подобное для кода, приведенного в первой ссылке?

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что iframe отсутствует? Он через js создается.

Comment: Возможно, в общем смысл вот в чем - при большом количестве видео на странице эта страница создает нагрузку на устройство, с которого просматривается страница из-за большого количества iframe на странице. Так вот при использовании этого кода iframe создается только при просмотре конкретного видео и только для него как я понял.

Comment: youtube имеет стандартное средство для данного случая https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551072/186083

Comment: Данный способ не совсем подходит ввиду особенности записи данных о видео в бд. То, что сейчас записывается прийдется переделывать, что не очень бы хотелось